# How to use componentsSeparatedByString with more than one

Tags: ios, nsstring

Im using componentsSeparatedByString to split a string into 2 pieces, into an array, separated by "-".  It turns out that some pieces of data are separated by "a" as well as "-".  Can I add a second 'predicate' to account for that situation?

Comment: The solution given by Graham works well, the only thing I find a bit dangerous is that the letter a is also use as a separator. I don't know what type of data it concerns, but just be sure that nowhere else the letter a is used as an actual character and not meant to be used as a separator.

Comment: Very good point.  I agree with you and I will tell the client to fix that immediately.

Comment: Usually charaters like ; or | are good/safe separators

Comment: Note that if the separator is " a " or " a:" or some such, you can still use that as a separator string, and not risk splitting "aardvark".  And you can manage both that and "-" by making a first pass with stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString: to convert the " a " substrings to "-" or vice-versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"-a"]];
```